# Accessing Laravel lang attributes

Tags: php, laravel

I want to use the `attributes` index that is inside the array returned by `/lang/es/validation.php`. Is there some function or way to access that array? I want to translate some Models attributes in places that aren't form validations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this if your default locale is not es:

```
trans('validation.attributes', [], 'es');
```

If your default locale is es, use this:

```
trans('validation.attributes');
```